# Finding substring in string with forward slash in Powershell scripts

Tags: powershell, substring, slash

I am trying to find sub-string in string using powershell script. Actually, I am reading a file line by line which contains thousands of paths. I am filtering each path coming from file. Path filters are finding sub-string in path.
But `Contains` function returns false when sub-string is `Sroot` or `TRoot`.

Following is my sample code.

```
foreach($line in Get-Content $filePath)
{
    # Line can contain
    # $line = $/Patil/TEMP/PRoot/Digvijay/Patil/1.png 
    # $line = $/Patil/TEMP/SRoot/Digvijay/Patil/2.png
    # $line = $/Patil/TEMP/TRoot/Digvijay/Patil/3.png
    if($line)
    {        
        if($line.Contains('RRoot')) # This condition works properly
        {                       
            # Process Rroot here
        }                       
        if($line.Contains('SRoot')) # This condition fails.
        {
            # Process SRoot here
        }
        if($line.Contains('TRoot')) # This condition fails.
        {
            # Process TRoot here
        }
    }
 }
```

**Input file is like:**

```
$/Patil/TEMP/PRoot/Digvijay/Patil/1.png
$/Patil/TEMP/SRoot/Digvijay/Patil/2.png
$/Patil/TEMP/TRoot/Digvijay/Patil/3.png
$/Patil/TEMP/WRoot/Digvijay/Patil/3.png
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in your code ... RRoot vs PRoot. But actually I cannot reproduce your issue. It's working just as exprected for me. If I'm not wrong it has to be an exact match when you use the string method `.Contains()`. It could be easier or more _forgiving_ when you use a `-match`. At least that's case insensitive. ;-)

Comment: Actually my original paths are different. I have modified the paths in path file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using multiple IFs

- you could use a switch controlled by the letter in front of `Root` determined by
- a RegEX storing the matched char in a capture group () recallable via `$Matches[1]`:

---

```
$filePath = '.\files.txt'
Get-Content $filePath | Where-Object {$_ -match '([PST])Root'} | ForEach-Object {
    $line = $_
    switch ($Matches[1]){
        'P' {'{0}={1}' -f $_,$line} # code in {} to execute on P
        'S' {'{0}={1}' -f $_,$line} # code in {} to execute on S
        'T' {'{0}={1}' -f $_,$line} # code in {} to execute on T
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
P=P:/TEMP/PRoot/Digvijay/Patil/1.png
S=S:/TEMP/SRoot/Digvijay/Patil/2.png
T=T:/TEMP/TRoot/Digvijay/Patil/3.png
```

**PS:** the `-match` operator and the switch statement are by default case insensitive,
to change that behaviour use `-cmatch` resp. switch with the `-CaseSensitive` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and it works as expected (changed `$line.Contains('RRoot')` to `$line.Contains('PRoot'`) to match the input example).

I think you might be struggling with a case sensitive problem.
I suggest that you try applying `tolower()` function to the string and then compare against a lower case string:

```
foreach($line in Get-Content $filePath)
{
    # Line can contain
    # $line = P:/TEMP/PRoot/Digvijay/Patil/1.png
    # $line = S:/TEMP/SRoot/Digvijay/Patil/2.png
    # $line = T:/TEMP/TRoot/Digvijay/Patil/3.png
    if($line)
    {
        $lineLower=$line.tolower()
        if($lineLower.Contains('proot')) # This condition works properly
        {                       
            Write-Host "PRoot"
        }                       
        if($lineLower.Contains('sroot')) # This condition fails.
        {
            Write-Host "SRoot"
        }
        if($lineLower.Contains('troot')) # This condition fails.
        {
            Write-Host "TRoot"
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the case-insensitive like operator `-ilike`

```
foreach($line in Get-Content $filePath)
{
    # Line can contain
    # $line = P:/TEMP/PRoot/Digvijay/Patil/1.png
    # $line = S:/TEMP/SRoot/Digvijay/Patil/2.png
    # $line = T:/TEMP/TRoot/Digvijay/Patil/3.png
    if($line)
    {        
        if($line -ilike "*RRoot*")) # This condition works properly
        {                       
            # Process Rroot here
        }                       
        if($line -ilike "*SRoot*")) # This condition fails.
        {
            # Process SRoot here
        }
        if($line -ilike "*TRoot*")) # This condition fails.
        {
            # Process TRoot here
        }
    }
 }
```